# Why do we observe the difference in the intensity pattern of Interference and Diffraction?

Tags: optics, interference, diffraction

As well said by Richard Feynman, “No one has ever been able to define the difference between interference and diffraction satisfactorily. It is just a question of usage, and there is no specific, important physical difference between them.”
Why do we observe the difference in the intensity pattern of Interference and Diffraction?

Comment: Which situation are you looking at that has a different intensity pattern for "interference" and "diffraction"?

Answer (score 1):

Interference: the observation that two or more waves arriving at the same place overlap and thus reinforce or cancel out one another.

Diffraction: the observation that plane waves going through an aperture of finite width, or more generally having a finite transverse extent, will spread out in the transverse direction as they propagate onwards. (And you can also generalize to a spreading in the direction of propagation for a short pulse or wave-packet).

Feynman's comment arises from the fact that when one calculates the details of a given diffraction pattern, one is doing a sum over a set of waves which mutually interfere. But the two terms are still useful since they convey a good general grasp of the sorts of things that propagating waves can do owing to the wavelike nature.

Answer (score 0):

If by "Why do we observe the difference in the intensity pattern of Interference and Diffraction?" you probably are referring to the very different appearance of diffraction one can observe from a pin hole when compared to, say, observing a linear grating.

One obvious answer is that the pin-hole is *small*, much smaller than a grating, for the linear dimension of a pin-hole is on the order of a wavelength while that of a good grating maybe thousands of a wavelengths, so the latter will be brighter.

But there is also a less trivial difference between the two. For the pin-hole you are mostly observing the interference between the portion of the incident wave that passes through the hole and the *edge wave* that the incident wave induces on the screen. The interference of the two will result in a circularly symmetric diffraction pattern but with radially decreasing local humps.
For a grating the dominant diffracted terms all come from a large number of interfering waves that pass through between the grooves and have roughly the same intensity; the result of their interference is a much flatter power distribution of the *humps* as we move in the direction perpendicular to the grooves.